# checkout_cart_update_items_after is not working

Tags: magento-1.7, checkout, event-observer

I'm stuck in this. The **checkout_cart_update_items_after** is not firing. I already put a log statement in the function but is not getting executed. Whereas 
**checkout_cart_product_add_after** is working fine.

```
<checkout_cart_product_add_after>
            <observers>
                <ysindia_customer_model_observer>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Ysindia_Customer_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>itemAdded</method>
                </ysindia_customer_model_observer>
            </observers>
        </checkout_cart_product_add_after>
        <checkout_cart_update_items_after>
            <observers>
                <ysindia_customer_model_observer>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Ysindia_Customer_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>checkCart</method>
                </ysindia_customer_model_observer>
            </observers>
</checkout_cart_update_items_after>
```

### Observer.php

```
class Ysindia_Customer_Model_Observer
{

public function checkCart(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){
     Mage::log("Items after", null, 'observer.log');
}

public function itemAdded(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    Mage::log("Add after", null, 'observer.log');
}

}
```

Please help me, thanks

Comment: How you check `checkout_cart_update_items_after` event?

Comment: I'm checking in a log file, checkout_cart_product_add_after log I can see but not checkout_cart_update_items_after.

Comment: Yeach, I remember that :) I mean how you trigger this events? `checkout_cart_update_items_after` is triggered e.g. after qty update in cart.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the type of your observer by Model instead of singleton:

```
<checkout_cart_product_add_after>
            <observers>
                <ysindia_customer_model_observer>
                    <type>model</type>
                    <class>Ysindia_Customer_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>itemAdded</method>
                </ysindia_customer_model_observer>
            </observers>
        </checkout_cart_product_add_after>
        <checkout_cart_update_items_after>
            <observers>
                <ysindia_customer_model_observer>
                    <type>model</type>
                    <class>Ysindia_Customer_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>checkCart</method>
                </ysindia_customer_model_observer>
            </observers>
</checkout_cart_update_items_after>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try with checkout_cart_product_update_after event if that help you.